# How to Ensure of Data MariaDB Galera Cluster's Safety?

Tags: security, mariadb, galera

MariaDB will send a copy of SST to every server which request for it even without checking whether it is in the gcomm:// list. So I can easily get other people's data by simply install a fresh copy of cluster and add the target server's address in gcomm:// list. Then how I can ensure my data's safety?

Answer (score 1):

Well... It seems that there is no way to implement auth unless I use mysqldump but finally I found an alternative way to secure my SST using certificate and private key.

Just self-sign a CA, and create a server private key and certificate, add them to `wsrep_provider_options` and everything is done. The attackers cannot retrieve a copy of SST as he cannot provide the same key pair for data signature and encryption.

The configuration file should be something like this:

```
[mysqld]
...
wsrep_provider_options="socket.ssl_key=/path/to/private.key; socket.ssl_cert=/path/to/certificate/file.crt; socket.ssl_ca=/path/to/CA.crt; socket.ssl_compression=YES";
```

I have written [an article about how to implement this idea](https://blog.ixnet.work/2016/04/12/enforce-galera-cluster-security/) in my blog, though it is in Simplified Chinese.